# Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

So I ran into this problem when trying to add a new sheet to a existing .xlsx file, I try everything I found on internet, and still cant create a new sheet on this existing file! Always is this error or something about .zip file

```
    def HCReport(self):

        wb2 = load_workbook(filename = 'HC-Template' +'.xlsx')
        ws2 = wb2['Raw Data']
        allCols = ['Employee Number', 'Full Name', 'Team']

        #xls = pd.ExcelFile(self.inputHC.get())
        xls = load_workbook(self.inputHC.get())
        if not 'Raw Data' in xls.sheetnames:
            xls.create_sheet('Raw Data')
        
        df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='Raw Data')
        print(df.head())
```

`Load_workbook` take to long to load the file, I have 16GB of RAM @32Mhz and when I run the code, this eate 11GB of it(Not response) if I end the task, the file got corrupted, If I wait, trow this error. The file size is around 6Mb to 12Mb. If I use the pd.ExcelFile, I cant create the new sheet Im using Python 3.9.5

Comment: Well if you suppose it is because its too large file, you can try loading it with `chunksize` in `pandas`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: @BijayRegmi IDK if is the file size, I read that can be... But I´m not sure at all